# Keep listview item selected even if view changes

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in fragment.
When I select a listview item, it gets highlighted and then I open another fragment.

Now, what I want is, when I move back to previous fragment, the list item should stay selected.

How can I do that?

Comment: By using `setSelectedIndex(..)` and `getSelectedIndex(...)` in `Adapter`

Comment: I'm not getting any such method. How should I call this

Comment: Check my answer and do it like that.

Comment: add some code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented like

add this two methods in your `Adapter`

```
 private int selectedIndex = ListView.NO_ID;

 public int getSelectedIndex() {
    return selectedIndex;
}

public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;

    // Re-draw the list by informing the view of the changes
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and in your `Adapter getView(...)` do

```
  // Highlight the selected item in the list
    if (selectedIndex != -1 && selectedIndex == position) {
            YourView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightred);
     }
```

and implement in `Fragment` in `setOnItemClickListener onItemClick(...)`  like

```
adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
```

save this selected value in some `preferences` and when you come back again call in `Fragment` `on resume(...)`

```
adapter.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK let's do this

declare one field in your adapter say

```
private int selectedPosition=-1;
```

now create a setter for this

```
private void setSelectedPosition(int position)
{
selectedPosition=position;
}
```

Now in your getView method

```
if(position==selectedPosition)
    {
    listItemView.setSelected(true);

    //OR

    listItemView.setBackgroundColor(<Some Color>);
    }
```

Now after setting the adapter when user tap and your OnItmeSelected called

```
adapter.setSelectedPosition(<your desired selected item position>);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```